# How to redirect everything from no-www to www Except for few files, using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, exclude

How to redirect everything from no-www to www **except for few files**, using .htaccess?

I am using the following .htaccess to redirect no-www to www.

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$ [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{http_host}/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

**How do I add exception for few files?**
for example:
1) example.com/page1.html should not be redirected to www.example.com
2) example.com/xml/page2.xml should not be redirected to www.example.com

Everything other then example.com/page1.html and example.com/xml/page2.xml should be redirected to www.example.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could chain your [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) directives, e.g.:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! ^/page1\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! ^/xml/page2\.xml$
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{http_host}/$1 [r=301,nc]
```